# ¿Como puedo hacer el diseño de mi ticket de una app?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app la cual tiene que imprimir un ticket en una impresora termica. La duda es como puedo hacer el diseño de mi ticket ya que solo imprime el texto que coloque en una caja de texto
este es el codigo donde se imprime el texto.

```
    String msg = textBox.getText().toString();
    msg+="\n";
    outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    lblPrinterName.setText("Printing Text...");
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias dar un poco mas de informacion sobre cual es el problema=?

Comment: necesito saber el codigo para darle un diseño a mi ticket ya que solo imprime el texto pero sin ningun diseño como los ticket de compra convencionales

Comment: Creo que deberias leer los links que te pase... desconozco si todas las impresoras termicas son iguales, pero como que estas pidiendo mucho sin decir nada.

Comment: solo necesito saber los comandos o el codigo en android para darle el diseño de mi ticket de compra, asi como un ticket de alguna tienda de ropa y eso

Comment: Esta pregunta la realizaste anteriormente, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/281351/como-puedo-hacer-el-dise%c3%b1o-para-mi-ticket-en-android no agregues preguntas repetidas, te sugiero revisar los enlaces que sugiere gbianchi para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, saludos. @MarcoRivera

Answer (score 0):

void sendData1() throws IOException {

```
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();

        String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);

        // the text typed by the user
        String msg = mEdtCodClient.getText().toString();
        msg += "\n";
        msg += "\n";
        msg += "       Nombre Empreza    \n";
        msg += "          Direccion      \n " +
                "     Numero de local     \n" +
                "     RFC:XXXX-XXXXXX-XXX      \n" +
                "     Tel. o Cel.      \n";
        msg += "--------------------------------\n";
        msg += "\n" + "Cod. " + mEdtCodClient.getText().toString() + " Nombre: " + medtNombre.getText().toString() + "\n";
        msg += "--------------------------------\n";
        msg += "\n" + fecha + "    Folio: " + medtTicket.getText().toString() + " \n";
        msg += "--------------------------------\n";
        //  msg += String.format("%1$5s %2$11s %3$6s %4$6s", "Prod", "Cant", "Impor", "Total");
        //  msg += "\n";
        // msg += "--------------------------------\n";

        // if (!Edit1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        //     msg += "\n " + String.format("%1$1s %2$3s %3$6s %4$7s", Pro1.getText(), Edit1.getText(), Impor1.getText(), Resultado.getText()) + "";
        // } else {

        //  }

        //   msg += "\n " + String.format("%1$-8s %2$3s %3$4s %4$6s", Pro20.getText(), text, Impor20.getText(), Tot20.getText());
        // msg += "\n--------------------------------";
        msg += "\n\n ";
        msg += "  cantidad en deuda: " + "      " + medtCredi.getText() + "\n";
        msg += "  Abono: " + "    " + mdabono.getText() + "\n";
        msg += "  Resta apagar: " + " resta    " + medtCredi.getText() + "\n";
        // msg += "  Total Value: " + "     " + TotTotal + "\n";
        // msg += "Cantidad en Letra: \n";
        // msg += " " + Info.getText().toString() + "\n";
        // msg += ""+ TareasProgramacion.cantidadConLetra(s19)+"\n";
        //Info.setText(NumLetras.Convertir(total + "", true));
        msg += "--------------------------------\n";
        msg += "\n\n ";
        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());

        // tell the user data were sent
        myLabel.setText("Enviado a imprimir");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```